# Populate table in pdf - objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I draw a table view in a pdf like  in   [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2) and it works when the table was so big like in tutorial , but i need a little table so i have changed :

```
int xOrigin = 350;
    int yOrigin = 200;

    int rowHeight = 10;
    int columnWidth = 35;

    int numberOfRows = 6;
    int numberOfColumns = 3;

    [self drawTableAt:CGPointMake(xOrigin, yOrigin) withRowHeight:rowHeight andColumnWidth:columnWidth andRowCount:numberOfRows andColumnCount:numberOfColumns];

    [self drawTableDataAt:CGPointMake(xOrigin, yOrigin) withRowHeight:rowHeight andColumnWidth:columnWidth andRowCount:numberOfRows andColumnCount:numberOfColumns];
```

and now the table is empty :( Have anyone any ideea about how can i populate again the table ?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the example you used in method

```
+(void)drawTableDataAt:(CGPoint)origin 
    withRowHeight:(int)rowHeight 
   andColumnWidth:(int)columnWidth 
      andRowCount:(int)numberOfRows 
   andColumnCount:(int)numberOfColumns
```

padding = 10

change your size to 20

Answer (score 0):

This method is used to show with what data the table is populated

```
+(void)drawTableDataAt:(CGPoint)origin 
    withRowHeight:(int)rowHeight 
   andColumnWidth:(int)columnWidth 
      andRowCount:(int)numberOfRows 
   andColumnCount:(int)numberOfColumns
{
    int padding = 10; 

    NSArray* headers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Quantity", @"Description", @"Unit price", @"Total", nil];
    NSArray* invoiceInfo1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"Development", @"$1000", @"$1000", nil];
    NSArray* invoiceInfo2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"Development", @"$1000", @"$1000", nil];
    NSArray* invoiceInfo3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"Development", @"$1000", @"$1000", nil];
    NSArray* invoiceInfo4 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"Development", @"$1000", @"$1000", nil];

    NSArray* allInfo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:headers, invoiceInfo1, invoiceInfo2, invoiceInfo3, invoiceInfo4, nil];

    for(int i = 0; i < [allInfo count]; i++)
    {
        NSArray* infoToDraw = [allInfo objectAtIndex:i];

        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) 
        {

            int newOriginX = origin.x + (j*columnWidth);
            int newOriginY = origin.y + ((i+1)*rowHeight);

            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(newOriginX + padding, newOriginY + padding, columnWidth, rowHeight);


            [self drawText:[infoToDraw objectAtIndex:j] inFrame:frame];
        }

    }

}
```

This below pasted method is used to draw the text within table cells

```
+(void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect
{

    CFStringRef stringRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)textToDraw;
    // Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter
    CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, NULL);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);


    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

    // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);

    // Get the graphics context.
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
    // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);


    // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
    // the current transform prior to drawing.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Draw the frame.
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);


    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(stringRef);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```

In case you want to set the text inside small cells with small font size

```
-(void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect
{
    int length=[textToDraw length];
    CFStringRef string = (__bridge CFStringRef) textToDraw;
    CFMutableAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);

    CFAttributedStringReplaceString (currentText,CFRangeMake(0, 0), string);
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Helvetica", 8.0f, nil);
    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(currentText,CFRangeMake(0, length),kCTFontAttributeName,font);

    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);

    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);
    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);
    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```